# Checkox not checked when clicked ASP Web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I'm using a jquery to intercept the click event of multiple checkbox controls but when I click a checkbox it doesn't remain checked.

```
<asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkbox" ID="chkEmployer" runat="server" Text="Employer" />

 var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
        checkBoxes.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.checked == true) {
                this.checked = true;
                show(this);
            }
            else
                hide(this);
        });
```

Comment: WebForms shouldn't make a real difference here unless there's other controls/elements that you omitted. That being the case, check this fiddle which shows your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/e4zp14g7/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do; are you hoping to hide the checkbox on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some JSFiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/665bLgz0/3/).

I've changed the event to change and it is remaining checked. I'm not sure if you want to stop the change from doing a post-back though.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(
```